# package resources only as jar using maven

Tags: maven, jar

I want to package only resources under directory `src/main/resources` into the jar published by maven. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Just to be sure, you don't want to include the compiled classes ?

Comment: @gontard right I don't want to include compiled classes. The resources i project A happen to be useful in project B. I put A.jar on B's classpath.

Comment: If i were you, i would create a project containing only the A resources. And this project will be a dependency of the projects A and B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following:

```
<build>
  <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
       <filtering>false</filtering>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
       ...
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  ...
</build>
```

As far as I can understand, it could be what you asked for.