# sbt git clone hangs for private repo

Tags: scala, github, sbt

I want to clone a remote git repository as part of my build, so added a dependency in my build.sbt this way -

```
val packagemain = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(uri("https://github.com/xyz/abc.git"))
```

I have setup caching of my GitHub credentials for cloning repositories through HTTPS by following instructions on [this](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/) page. This works, that is, when I clone this repo manually it does so without asking for username/password.

However, when I launch SBT, it simply **hangs** after the following statements on console -

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/bharadwaj/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/bharadwaj/xyz/project/project
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/bharadwaj/xyz/project
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/bharadwaj/project/project
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/bharadwaj/project
Cloning into '/Users/bharadwaj/.sbt/0.13/staging/c682e5428a4ee10acbaf/abc'...
```

Am using SBT version 0.13.5, Git version 2.0.4 on a Mac-OSX.

I have tried going into the SBT staging directory and trying a 'git pull' - it does so without any issues. Its only when cloning thru SBT

Comment: Does it work if you use "git@github.com:xyz/abc.git" instead of cloning over "https"?

Comment: Nope. I get => Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 3: git@github.com:abc/xyz.git

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that accessing `https://github.com/xyz/abc.git` will redirect to `https://github.com/xyz/abc` with a 301 Moved Permanently. The 301 is probably fooling sbt.

Try using an ssh URL, for example

```
ssh://git@github.com/xyz/abc.git
```

And make sure your ssh key is setup properly to access this private git repo.

Comment: made the change and the earlier error disappeared. however now sbt tries to resolve the dependency project as a ivy/maven project looking for pom/ivy etc. The github repo I am trying to pull in is not a code repository. Its just some plain files. How can I tell sbt to simply download this github repo without treating it as a code/jar dependency?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. After the build, where do you want these "plain files" to end up? Inside a jar as resources, or something else? Also may I ask what is in the plain files and why it's required for your build?

Comment: actually these plain files are not required for the build - am packaging my application using 'sbt-native-packager' and want these plain files to be downloaded from github and placed in the packaged zip of my application. The part to package files from the filesystem is simple - but having a sbt task that can download non-build dependency files from github is non-trivial for me

Comment: Since sbt is expecting a maven-compatible package, you might consider placing these plain files into a package, as resources, so that sbt will include them as it does any type of resource. I can't find an sbt example, but this is sometimes done with maven, leading me to believe that you might achieve a similar result with sbt. (Alternatively, you could create an sbt-compatible jar using maven or ivy and include that as a dependency in your sbt build.)
Maven example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216742/package-resources-only-as-jar-using-maven